# Make utility complains about "undefined reference" when I tried to make TPC-E test

Tags: c++, makefile, debian, ld, tpc

The problem is compounded by the fact that I am far from programming.

I need to use the TPC-E test. I downloaded the source codes from their [website](http://www.tpc.org/TPC_Documents_Current_Versions/download_programs/tools-download-request5.asp?bm_type=TPC-E&bm_vers=1.14.0&mode=CURRENT-ONLY).

There is a miserable and almost meaningless ReadMe.
Here are its contents:

```
To use the Makefile you must first set the following environment variables 
to match your system and compiler requirements:

CXX: path and name of compiler
    ex: export CXX=/opt/SUNWspro/bin/CC  (C++ compiler on Solaris)
CCFLAGS: compiler options
    ex: export CCFLAGS="-g -O"  
        -g enable debug
        -O optimize code
LDFLAGS: linker/loader options
    ex: export LDFLAGS="-g"
LIBS: extra libraries to link in
    ex: export LIBS="-lpthread"
```

According to the instructions there, I created the necessary environment variables (I just removed the -g switch from the CCFLAGS variable). After that, I ran the make utility and got more than five thousand lines of errors. Apparently he lacks some libraries. On this my knowledge ends.

Here are some error messages received:

```
...

/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.o: in function `TPCE::CDateTime::Validate(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)': DateTime.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.cpp:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.cpp:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.cpp:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: DateTime.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'

...

/usr/bin/ld: error.cpp:(.text._ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD0Ev[_ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `std::exception::~exception()'
/usr/bin/ld: error.cpp:(.text._ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD0Ev[_ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD5Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: error.o: in function `TPCE::CSystemErr::~CSystemErr()':error.cpp:(.text._ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD2Ev[_ZN4TPCE10CSystemErrD5Ev]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'

...

/usr/bin/ld: locking.cpp:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: locking.cpp:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()'
/usr/bin/ld: locking.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::runtime_error'
/usr/bin/ld: locking.cpp:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/usr/bin/ld: locking.o: in function `TPCE::CMutex::lock()':locking.cpp:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'

...
```

A search on the internet made me think of installing the libboost-all-dev package, but that didn't help. In the end, I gave up - I’m completely incomprehensible to the terminology and I don’t have time to study C ++ programming.

Operating System - Debian 10

Questions: which libraries need to be installed and is there anyone who used these tests, how to adapt them to PostgreSQL?

[Full error log (892 230 bytes)](https://yadi.sk/d/QcaY3Dmdv_00-w)

Comment: My first guess would be that you're linking with a C compiler (such as gcc) rather than a C++ compiler.  So you end up linking to the C runtime.  Which compiler do you use?  What value for CXX env. variable?

Comment: You probably want to share the make COMMANDS (gcc ... g++ ...) that generated the above error messages.

Comment: @G.M. export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc      
export CCFLAGS="-O"      
export LDFLAGS="-g"      
export LIBS="-lpthread"

Comment: @dash-o
I just typed 'make' that's all

Comment: In accordance with G.M. I replaced /usr/bin/gcc with /usr/bin/c++ and the build was successful. A few warnings about deprecated functions were displayed, but everything seems to be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc
```

with

```
export CXX=/usr/bin/c++
```